# get wordpress only footer on external php page

Tags: php, wordpress, footer

I am working on a application where i only need to get **wordpress** footer
on outside **php** page i am using below code

```
<?php require('../wp-blog-header.php'); ?>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

but it is loading **NULL**,when i useing below code

```
<?php require('../wp-blog-header.php'); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

it loads both header and footer but i want to load only footer please let me know what should i do

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Refer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43810396/128761).

You can use `get_footer()` function.

```php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/wp-blog-header.php';

// create false $wp_styles to prevent errors.
$wp_styles = new \stdClass();
$wp_styles->queue = [];

get_footer();
```

In case that your file is the same location with **wp-blog-header.php** then use the same path as shown above.

**Warning!** The result maybe invalid HTML as the elements are closed without open. Example `</div>` without matched `<div>`.

##### Alternative solutions.

- Use `cURL` to fetch your home page and then use [PHP Dom](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to grab only specific HTML part. Ideas: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42683090/get-a-dom-element-from-website-using-php), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182857/using-php-dom-document-to-select-html-element-by-its-class-and-get-its-text)
- Use AJAX to fetch your home page and then use JS Dom to grab only specific HTML part. ([See reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713870/is-it-possible-to-get-a-part-of-page-in-an-ajax-get-request?lq=1)).

These 2 choices, I can't show the code because each WordPress theme use different HTML elements and styles.

Comment: get_footer() returning null

Comment: if i use get_header() then it works but return both header and footer

Comment: @XenBulletins Refer from [WP doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_footer/) the `get_footer()` function call theme's footer[-xxx].php. If it really is `null` then check your WP theme that footer file render something or not. It is hardly possible to be `null`. My result: the theme's footer was rendered before error messages.